# Заменить текст кнопки php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть кнопка на сайте wordpress, не могу изменить ее текст. Пробовал вставлять функции в functions.php , но ничего не меняется. Нужно заменить текст "Оформление заказа" на "Оформить" Помогите, пожалуйста!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно заменить текст "Оформление заказа" на "Оформить"

Разработчики WC рекомендуют делать подобные замены с помощью плагина [Say What](https://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/). См. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/

А я порекомендую с помощью [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) создать свой лангпак.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую